# DirectX 9 "unresolved external symbol" problem

Tags: c++, directx-9, unresolved-external

I have been working on learning DirectX for a couple days and have run into a problem. I have been following a books example and have solved several annoying problems that have come up, but have been unsuccessful at solving my most recent one. The compiler states that I have an unresolved external symbol whenever I try to compile. Here is the error code below.

```
1>game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct IDirect3DSurface9 * __cdecl 
LoadSurface(char *,unsigned long)" (?LoadSurface@@YAPAUIDirect3DSurface9@@PADK@Z) referenced in
function "int __cdecl Game_Init(struct HWND__ *)" (?Game_Init@@YAHPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Work\Debug\Work.exe : fatal error
LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am running: [compiler: Visual Studios 2008]   [Operating system: Windows 7 64bit professional]

Here a sample of the code and where it seem to be taking place. (I hope I gave enough info)

```
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 kitty_image[7];
SPRITE kitty;
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 back;

//timing variable
long start = GetTickCount();

//initializes the game
int Game_Init(HWND hwnd)
{
char s[20];
int n;

//set random number seed
srand(time(NULL));

//load the sprite animation
for (n=0; n<6; n++)
{
    sprintf(s, "cat%d.bmp",n+1);
    kitty_image[n] = LoadSurface(s, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,0,255));
    if (kitty_image[n] == NULL)
        return 0;
}

back = LoadSurface("background.bmp", NULL );


//initialize the sprite's properties
kitty.x = 100;
kitty.y = 150;
kitty.width = 96;
kitty.height = 96;
kitty.curframe = 0;
kitty.lastframe = 5;
kitty.animdelay = 2;
kitty.animcount = 0;
kitty.movex = 8;
kitty.movey = 0;

//return okay
return 1;
}
```

I have linked both d3d9.lib and d3dx9.lib to my project and have included all neccesary header files that I know of (d3d9.h, d3dx9.h). Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the linker is complaining that there is no such function `LoadSurface`.  Where did you define it?

Comment: Sorry... should say "the linker...".

Comment: As far as I can tell LoadSurface is a function inside <d3dx9.h>. It was included with the Directx 9 SDK and I have no problems linking the libraries or including the header files. It's pretty much stating thats my problem, but I have no idea how to fix it or even begin diagnosing it. (a.k.a. I am a beginner)

Comment: I installed the DirectX SDK to be sure and found that there is no such function in any of the DirectX header files; the closest I could find is D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172900.aspx ). Perhaps you are getting this code from a sample application but you didn't copy or include all of the source/header files?